# Conjuration with illusion buffs possible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wanted to go for a destruction/conjuration/illusion build where I would summon something then buff it with courage then shoot fire from my hands.

When I used courage on my flame atronach it said it resisted it so this is a real bummer for me. So before I move any further I wish to know if all the atronachs are immune to courage. It also looks like rally and call to arms are only aoe versions of courage so I probably won't need those.

Although I'm looking at this http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion and it says fortify health for 25 points, does that mean it only grants 25 more health to the target? If that's the case it doesn't seem very good, even with the dual casting perk for 2.2 times.

Comment: yes fortify health for 25 points indeed only grants 25 health to the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic resistance and absoprtion are kinda wonky in Elder Scrolls games. In Oblivion, those with the sign of the Atronach absorbed their own summoning spells half the time. Try raising some zombies, they shouldn't resist your magic.

Answer (score 3):

illusion magic doesn't affect undead, atronachs, or machinations. However there is a master level perk that allows illusion magic to be used on them ( undead, atronachs,machinations.)